# How can I use ember-simple-auth with ember-cli?

Tags: ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to adapt the instructions on https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth for an app build using v0.0.28 of ember-cli. I am fairly new to ember-cli and use of AMD modules.

Can anyone help with the proper way/place to import ember-simple-auth rather than the global namespace as covered in the README?

The following initializer

```
import SimpleAuth from 'vendor/ember-simple-auth/amd/ember-simple-auth';

export default {
  name: 'authentication',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    SimpleAuth.setup(container, application);
  }
}
```

Is compiled to

```
define("myapp/initializers/ember-simple-auth", 
  ["vendor/ember-simple-auth/amd/ember-simple-auth","exports"],
  function(__dependency1__, __exports__) {
    "use strict";
    var SimpleAuth = __dependency1__["default"];

    __exports__["default"] = {
      name: 'authentication',
      initialize: function(container, application) {
        SimpleAuth.setup(container, application);
      }
    }
  });//# sourceURL=myapp/initializers/ember-simple-auth.js
```

And `__dependency1__` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the installation instructions for ember-cli in the README: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#installation - unfortunately it's not yet possible to import individual parts of Ember.SimpleAuth though.